# angular js: Can't delete my uploaded files

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I m new with angular js this days i m trying to upload files and delete this uploaded file but now i m stuck with delete file problem

here is my `html` code:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="files in table.process_data.attachments">
        <a target="_self" class="col-sm-6" href="sales/download/{{files.filepath}}/{{files.name}}">{{files.name}}</a> 
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger col-sm-offset-3" ng-click="table.deleteFile(files.id)" value="delete"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and here is my `angularjs` delete function:

```
 vm.deleteFile = function (id) {
            $scope.getJson('sales/removeAttachment', id, function (r) {
                if (r.error == null) {
                    vm.editSales(vm.edit_id);
                    vm.showToastSuccess('file deleted');
                } else {
                    vm.showToastFail(r.error);
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: Would this be of some help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745755/angular-ng-file-upload-delete

Comment: no its different issue

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: You must at least specify what is the problem! Console logs some error? Http request is wrong? Is your backend working? Hard to help you with given informations.

Comment: Here Is My Back-End Not Working !..but now i m reach to the solution !

Answer (score 0):

I Think This Will Help You!

```
vm.deleteFile = function (id) {
                $scope.getJson('file_upload/removeAttachment', id, function (r) {
                    if (r.success) {
                        vm.editSales(vm.edit_id);
                        vm.showToastSuccess('file deleted');
                    } else if (r.error) {
                        vm.showToastFail(r.error);
                    } else {
                        vm.showToastFail('something went wrong during delete!');
                    }
                });
            };
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.